# What are good options for accessing WSDL Webservices in Groovy?

Tags: web-services, groovy, wsdl

What are good options for accessing Webservices that are defined with WSDL from Groovy? I've looked at [groovyws](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) and while it appears to work ok for basic stuff I've run into issues with complex WSDL in the passed. It also appears to no longer be under active development. Are there any other good Groovy options for accessing webservices or should I just pick a Java API and call it through Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using GroovyWS, and haven't found an alternative.  If GroovyWS manages to parse the WSDL, it seems to work nicely enough.  In the case where it wouldn't parse the WSDL, I switched service APIs completely.